# Access filter based on table relationships

Tags: ms-access

I’d be very grateful for a little help in improving the following:

Table1

A B

1

2

3 2

4 2

5

6

7 6

8 6

9 6

I have a single table than contains 2 fields, A and B (sorry...having a little problem trying to separate the fields better here...new to stackoverflow)

I have a user form with one multi-select listbox. This listbox is populated with field A.
The user is able to select any number of items in this listbox.

In the table, field B relates to field A such that an entry in B allows for a shorthand method of selecting items in A – it is this ‘shorthand’ that I am trying to achieve.

Examples:

- If the Listbox selection was 1,6 then the actual selection would be 1,6,7,8,9 (6 relates to 7,8,9)
- If the Listbox selection was 1,5 then the actual selection would be 1,5 (no relationships here)
- If the listbox selection was 2,6 the actual selection would be 2,3,4,6,7,8,9

The entries in B must also appear in A since the relationships can be enabled or disabled by the user (here, only the selections in A would be used). In either case, post-processing will take place on the selections made.

What I would like to know is – is there an easy way of populating an array e.g. Selection() with all selections when A:B relationships is enabled? This will ultimately feed into a sql "IN(...)" statement. 
I did something similar to this in Excel however I’m converting a project to Access and was wondering if there was some sql method that might accomplish this in one step.

(Edit:)
I have constructed the following which seems to work, so far:

```
SELECT A
FROM Table1
WHERE A IN(1,2,6) OR B IN(1,2,6);
```

Filtered return: 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 (exactly what I want)

For the above, I can use VBA to extract the user-selected items in the listbox and then populate these entries into the "IN(...)" statements above.

What I now need to do is to be able to enter the above results into a second downstream search query, in particular, populate another "IN(....)" statement with the filtered returns from the above query. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In design view, select the Rowsource of the child combobox, that is the one that changes depending on the parent.  It will ask if you want to build a SQL Query reference.

Select the field you want to display, and the field you want to relate, and use 
[Forms]![YourForm]![cboParentCombo] as the criteria of the related field.  Make sure both CBOs are set to include both the visible field and the related field, and make sure the "Bound columns" match, i.e. in design view if field 1 on cbo1 binds to field 2 on cbo2, make sure the bound columns of both reflects that.

I have a dropdown where you select a department from a list.  Another field in that table, linked in the combo but not visible, is a number showing department type.  The next combo displays a category, and has a not visible field that's also the department type.  I put [Forms]![AddNewCase]![cboDepartment] in the criteria of the hidden related field in the rowsource sql query, and my bound columns are both set to 2.  Whenever department changes, the category options change to reflect it.

Hope that helps fix it

Comment: Thanks for your time, Acuntud.This is really appreciated.